# jquery tabs problem

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am new to jquery and created 10 tabs using :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('#tabs').tabs();
 });
```

Then I used `<li>a href="#tabs-1"> MYTAB </a> </li>` htlm code for my tabs.

I managed to create static tabs and now I can go back and forth to see the content of my tabs.

The problem I am facing is each tab contains a seperate link to a different website where users need to enter their passwords/usernames. Some of my users werent able to do that from their phones etc.

I then changed my design to ajax and it works fine but page refreshes each time (users do not want that).

```
<li>a href="url"> MYTAB </a> </li>
```

What is the best solution to get around from this?

Thanks

```
My script:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<META name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full">
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body style="font-size:62.5%;">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">site1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">site2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">site3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">site4</a></li>
      </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
            <iframe src="url1" width="100%" height="500">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p> </iframe>
            </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
            <iframe src="url2" width="100%" height="500">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>  
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
            <iframe src="url3" width="100%" height="500">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>  
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
            <iframe src="url4">
            <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p></iframe>  
    </div>



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how about you post the code that's causing problems instead of the tab code that seems to work fine... what's this ajax code that's at issue?

Comment: this is the code that is working properly on a desktop. it doesnt work on an ipad, iphone..etc .since no login info is entered for each tab the tabs does not bring in the content. If i use ajax it asks for user authentication and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use the inbuilt Ajax tabs?

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
            ajaxOptions: {
                error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
                    $( anchor.hash ).html(
                        "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                        "If this wouldn't be a demo." );
                }
            }
        });
    });
    </script>

<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Preloaded</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content1.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content2.html">Tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content3-slow.php">Tab 3 (slow)</a></li>
        <li><a href="ajax/content4-broken.php">Tab 4 (broken)</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus. Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa et lorem. Mauris dapibus lacus auctor risus. Aenean tempor ullamcorper leo. Vivamus sed magna quis ligula eleifend adipiscing. Duis orci. Aliquam sodales tortor vitae ipsum. Aliquam nulla. Duis aliquam molestie erat. Ut et mauris vel pede varius sollicitudin. Sed ut dolor nec orci tincidunt interdum. Phasellus ipsum. Nunc tristique tempus lectus.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->



<div class="demo-description">
<p>Fetch external content via Ajax for the tabs by setting an href value in the tab links.  While the Ajax request is waiting for a response, the tab label changes to say "Loading...", then returns to the normal label once loaded.</p>
<p>Tabs 3 and 4 demonstrate slow-loading and broken AJAX tabs, and how to handle serverside errors in those cases. Note: These two require a webserver to interpret PHP. They won't work from the filesystem.</p>
</div><!-- End demo-description -->
```