# jquery ajax tabs question

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I am a newbie to jquery ajax tabs and tried to create ajax tabs. The content pages are located on different servers/domains. My question is when i use the code below to implement ajax tabs these pages do not show up. When I create iframe pages on the server where my tabs are housed and use those links as my href link it works.

Do I need to do that every time I want to add a new tab? My requirement is to get away from doing that.

Thanks,

(full code: [jquery tabs problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5872315/jquery-tabs-problem/5900691#5900691))

```
<li><a href="ajax/content.htlm">Tab1</a></li> --> 

<li><a href="ajax/content.htlm">Tab2</a></li> --> 

<li><a href="ajax/content.htlm">Tab3</a></li> --> 

<li><a href="ajax/content.htlm">Tab4</a></li> -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you can't make cross-domain ajax requests due to security issues.

And, for the second question: Yes you could fix it by using iframes, but then they arent AJAX anymore. You could append a new iframe dynamically and set the src to the url you wanted to fetch the stuff from, or just use a single iframe that switches source when a tab is clicked.

Comment: Thanks Garuda. The problem I am facing is my javascript back buttons which are located in my pages do not work when i insert them to iframes. Thats why I wanted to use direct urls. Any thoughts?